# references for singularities: does quotient singularities imply gorenstein?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Is there a good place where to learn about singularities of algebraic varieties?

OK, this question is terribly vague, so I'll ask what I'm currently interested in: if X is a smooth variety and G is a finite group, then is $X/G$ Gorenstein? If true, what would a reference be?

Comment: This is outside my area of knowledge, but [this paper](http://www.pitt.edu/~borisov/Documents/papers/quot_fact_RH.pdf) discusses a procedure for modifying a quotient singularity that is not Gorenstein to a different quotient singularity that is Gorenstein. So I presume, based on context, that the answer to your question is no, though I don't know a counterexample myself. However, I thought I would mention this in case the technique of the paper is helpful to you.

Comment: ah, interesting. I had never heard of a gorenstein index before. Is this definition of gorenstein the same as the usual one? (also, of being gorenstein I only need the dualising complex to be a bundle)

Answer (score 2):

Here is [a related question on mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/57505/a-geometric-reference-for-affine-gorenstein-varieties-and-singularities).

It sounds like the relevant part of 'Gorenstein' here is that the canonical divisor is Cartier.  Or, in other words, the canonical sheaf is invertible.  This is *not* necessarily true for quotients of smooth varieties.

Here is a simple example of an isolated quotient singularity which is non-Gorenstein:  Let $X \cong \mathbb{C}^3 = \mathrm{Spec}\,\mathbb{C}[z_1,z_2,z_3]$ and let $G \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$ act on $X$ as $(z_1, z_2, z_3) \to (-z_1, -z_2,-z_3)$.  Then $X/G = \mathrm{Spec}\,\mathbb{C}[z_1^2,z_2^2,z_3^2,z_1 z_2, z_1 z_3, z_2 z_3]$, and this is not Gorenstein.  There are (at least) a couple of ways to see this:

- If you know toric geometry, it is a simple exercise to show that $K_{X/G}$ is not Cartier.
- Roughly, the stalk of $\omega_X$ at the origin is generated by $dz_1\wedge dz_2\wedge dz_3$, and this is not preserved by $G$, so $\omega_{X/G\setminus\{0\}}$ cannot be extended to a line bundle at the origin.  In more detail, $\omega_{X/G}$ has three independent sections in a neighbourhood of the origin:
  $z_1dz_1\wedge dz_2\wedge dz_3~,~ z_2dz_1\wedge dz_2\wedge dz_3~,~ z_3dz_1\wedge dz_2\wedge dz_3$.

Answer (score 1):

The standard textbook references for learning singularities and their resolution are:

- **Greuel/Lossen/Shustin** - *[Introduction to Singularities And Deformations](http://amzn.com/3540283803)*, Springer 2007.
- **Kollár, J.** - *[Lectures on Resolution of Singularities](http://books.google.es/books?id=Oygejj1QFhgC&lpg=PP1&dq=Resolution%20of%20Singularities&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false)*, Princeton University Press 2007.
- **Cutkosky, S. D.** - *[Resolution of Singularities](http://books.google.es/books?id=OkAppJ7dXsgC&lpg=PP1&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false)*, AMS Graduate Studies in Mathematics 2004.
- **Kollár/Kovács** - *[Singularities of the Minimal Model Program](http://www.cambridge.org/es/knowledge/isbn/item7078385/?site_locale=es_ES)*, Springer 2013.
- **Hauser et al.** - *[Resolution of Singularities, a Research Textbook](http://books.google.es/books?id=rOlNQqTYF60C&lpg=PA340&dq=Hauser%20et%20al.%20-%20Resolution%20of%20Singularities,%20a%20research%20textbook&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false)*, Birkhauser 2000.

Specially, Kollár's and Cutkosky's are great books giving many examples and proving Hironaka's famous resolution theorem. Maybe you could find there the kind of topics you are interested in. For an introduction to singularities and a deeply conceptual overview towards such a theorem, there is the fantastic freely available article:

- **Hauser, H.** - *[The Hironaka theorem on resolution of singularities (Or: a proof we always wanted to understand)](http://homepage.univie.ac.at/herwig.hauser/Publications/The%20Hironaka%20Theorem%20on%20resolution%20of%20singularities/The%20Hironaka%20Theorem%20on%20resolution%20of%20singularities.pdf)*, Bulletin of the AMS vol. 40 no.3, p.323-403, 2003.